# Equality on union of an increasing sequence of subspaces of vector space and second dual

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $V_n$ be an increasing sequence$(V_n \subset V_{n+1})$ of subspaces of $V$. Does the following equality holds
in $V^{**}$

> $\left (\overline {\bigcup_n V_n}\right)^{**}= \overline {\bigcup_n V_n^{**}}$

Basically we need to show that $\bigcup_n V_n^{**}$ is dense in $\left (\overline {\bigcup_n V_n}\right)^{**}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. To see this take $V=c_0$ and let $e_1 , e_2 , ....,$ where $e_i= (0,0,...0,1,0...)$. Denote $V_n =\mbox{span}\{e_1, ..., e_n \}.$ It iis easy to see that $$\overline{\bigcup V_n } =c_0 $$ and hence $$\left(\overline{\bigcup V_n } \right)^{**} =\ell^{\infty} .$$
But since $V_n $ are finite dimensional thus $$(V_n , ||\cdot ||_{\infty})^{**} =(V_n , ||\cdot ||_{\infty} )$$ shortly $$V_n^{**} = V_n $$ since on finite dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent. But then $$\overline{\bigcup V_n^{**} } =\overline{\bigcup V_n } \neq \ell^{\infty}$$ since sequence $$(1, 1, ....,1,..)$$
connot be approximated (in the supremum norm) by any sequence with only finite number of coordinates different to zero.

Comment: The bidual of $\ell^1$ is not $\ell^\infty$. However, one can consider these finite dimensional spaces $V_n$ subspaces of $c_0$ so that $\bigcup_n V_n$ is dense in $c_0$ but not in $\ell^\infty$ (at least, in the norm topology, although the union is dense in the weak$^*$-topology $\sigma(\ell^\infty,\ell^1)$).

Comment: My previous comment refers to a former version of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I've edited I changed the answer.